# Two left-floating cols plus right-floating sidebar Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My goal is to achieve the following image on my page:
[image]

I managed to achieve this with the HTML and CSS you can find below, but it doesn't seem very viable, because the sidebar is losing it's physical height because of the `position: absolute`.

I'm wondering if it's possible to make one row with two columns on the left and a sidebar on the right, without having to use positioning.
I tried `position: relative` with a negative `top`, but since the top `col-md-9` has a changing height (depending on what is entered), I can't give it a negative `top`. It'll simply be too static and impossible to maintain.

Changing the order in the HTML doesn't change anything, since the physical height of the sidebar will move the 2nd content down.

```css
.sidebar { 
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-9">
    Changing content
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 sidebar">
    Sidebar
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-9">
    More content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you seen this example on http://getbootstrap.com/examples/blog/?

Comment: @dschu The problem is that I have two "blog-main" on the left, if that makes sense? I can easily place it to the right of the 2nd `col-md-9`, no problems there. Problem is placing it to the right of BOTH `col-md-9`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use `xs` columns for this example, but you can change to `md` in your page.

Firstly create a 9-column and a 3-column div. Then put two divs inside the 9-column one.

```css
.content, .sidebar {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.content {
  background-color: navy;
  color: white;
}

.sidebar {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row wrapper">
  <div class="col-xs-9">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="content">Content</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="content">Content</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
    <div class="sidebar">Sidebar</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can nest col-x-x inside other col-x-x
You just have to create 2 parents: content and sidebar, then add multiple contents into the content parent :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          Content
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
          More content
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3 sidebar">
        Sidebar
    </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have more that 12 columns in a row unless it is not defined in your custom grid.

What you can try is this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                     Changing content
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    More content
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3" style="position: relative;">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 sidebar">
                 Sidebar
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div
```

Answer (score 1):

As a solution, you can make sidebar to stay at the right side of screen if you'll make left section `overflow: auto`.

```css
.sidebar {
  height: 100vh;
  background: lightgreen;
}
.left-section {
  height: 100vh;
  background: lightblue;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-9 left-section">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          Changing content
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          More content
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 sidebar">
        Sidebar
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```